# How to group by data in one column into multiple columns keeping rows

Tags: r

| Identifier | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 511016 | 75.72911 |
| 511016 | 79.01783 |
| 511016 | 74.87570 |
| 511029 | 72.75873 |
| 511029 | 74.41798 |
| 511029 | 78.56112 |

The dataset consists of two columns (as above) but 77,000 rows. The first column is the  'name' vector and the second the value.
I need to transform the data so that the first column has just one value for the identifier and after this, the columns take all the values that the respective identifier has.
Like this:

| Identifier | Value 1 | Value 2 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 511016 | 75.72911 | 79.01783 |  |
| 511029 | 72.75873 | 74.41798 |  |

I have been able to use group_keys to produce a single column with the identifiers but cannot get the values to match in this way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
dat <- structure(list(Identifier = c(511016L, 511016L, 511016L, 511029L, 
                              511029L, 511029L), 
               Value = c(75.72911, 79.01783, 74.8757, 72.75873, 
                         74.41798, 78.56112)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
dat %>% 
  group_by(Identifier) %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "obs", 
                    values_from = "Value", 
                    names_prefix="value")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#> # Groups:   Identifier [2]
#>   Identifier value1 value2 value3
#>        <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     511016   75.7   79.0   74.9
#> 2     511029   72.8   74.4   78.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(~Identifier,  ~Value,
511016,     75.72911,
511016,     79.01783,
511016,     74.87570,
511029,     72.75873,
511029,     74.41798,
511029,     78.56112
) 


df %>% 
  group_by(Identifier) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "Identifier",  names_from = row_id,
              values_from = Value, 
              names_glue = "{.value}{row_id}") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: You don't have to double (dplyr) instead: `library(dplyr) library(tidyr)` or only `library(tidyverse)`:-)

Comment: ah I wasn't thinking, you are completely right, I edited it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your df has two columns, One similar Option is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Identifier) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(colnames(df[2]), row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Value)
```

```
  Identifier `Value 1` `Value 2` `Value 3`
       <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     511016      75.7      79.0      74.9
2     511029      72.8      74.4      78.6
```